# How to identify the wireless network card on my laptop?

Tags: linux, wifi, slackware

```
bash-4.1# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HEM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8039 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 14)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g (rev 01)
08:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
08:09.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
08:09.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C843 MMC Host Controller (rev 12)
08:09.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
08:09.4 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev ff)
```

Platform:

```
bash-4.1# cat /etc/slackware-version && uname -a
Slackware 13.1.0
Linux anisha 2.6.33.4-smp #2 SMP Wed May 12 22:47:36 CDT 2010 i686 Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T2370  @ 1.73GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

which entry shows the wireless card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the BCM4312 at 07:00.0. Note the "802.11" following.

Comment: What made you recognize it? I don't know what the "802.11" represents; I haven't done anything with networking before.

Comment: @Anisha - 802.11 is the common wireless networking standard. Just like IEEE1394 is the firewire standard

Comment: It's actually [an entire set of standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11). Not that a quick trip to Google couldn't have told one that of course.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Thanks for the explanation. Perhaps I should check out other networking standards too.